# How to import a file 3 folders down

Tags: reactjs

I'm editing a file Product.jsx with the file path: `src\components\Products\Product\Product.jsx`

I want to import a CartContext file with the path: `src\context\CartContext.js`

I am trying to do this: `import { CartContext } from "../../../context/CartContext";`
to import it, but i get the error:

```
Failed to compile
./src/components/frontpage/Product.js
Module not found: You attempted to import ../../../context/CartContext which falls outside of the project src/ directory. 
Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

I never had import errors and I have no idea what is going on.

Auto import is not working either..

Comment: The error suggests the file having a problem is in `./src/components/frontpage/Product.js`, rather than `src\components\Products\Product\Product.jsx` Are you moving files at all during the build process?

Comment: Thanks so much, you saved me. I was making a new Product file and I did not realize the old one was the one bugging. It was a quick fix

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the anwser is "I was editing the wrong file"...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was editing the wrong file, which was was in src\components\frontpage\Product.js, resulting in the "falls outside of the project src/ directory" error.